# After adding Global Route Guards in Vue Router the URL won't update anymore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've been following the VueMastery courses and stumbled upon an unexpected problem I cannot seem to resolve myself.

Without using the Global Router Guards the URL updates normally on both modes. But as soon as I add the following hooks to my router (router/index.js) I get no errors whatsoever, but the URL won't update anymore:

```
router.beforeEach((routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {
  NProgress.start();
  next();
});

router.afterEach((routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {
  NProgress.done();
  next();
});
```

Using:

- @vue/cli 4.2.3
- vue-router 3.1.5

My complete router (router/index.js) file contains the following script:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import EventList from "../views/EventList.vue";
import store from "@/store/index";
import NProgress from "nprogress";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "event-list",
    component: EventList
  },
  {
    path: "/event/create",
    name: "event-create",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "event-create" */ "../views/EventCreate.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/event/:id",
    name: "event-show",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "event-show" */ "../views/EventShow"),
    props: true,
    beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
      store.dispatch("event/fetchEvent", routeTo.params.id).then(event => {
        routeTo.params.event = event;
        next();
      });
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {
  NProgress.start();
  next();
});

router.afterEach((routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {
  NProgress.done();
  next();
});

export default router;
```

And is imported and used in my main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

// Automatic Global Component Registraton
import upperFirst from "lodash/upperFirst";
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";

// NProgress
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";

const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  "./components",
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  false,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /Base[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
);

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      // Gets the file name regardless of folder depth
      fileName
        .split("/")
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
    )
  );

  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    // Look for the component options on `.default`, which will
    // exist if the component was exported with `export default`,
    // otherwise fall back to module's root.
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  );
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

What could possibly cause the URL to not update anymore? I tried using the default hash mode but the same problem occurred. The URL's just won't update when clicking the router-links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be an error telling you that

> TypeError: next is not a function

because `next` is not defined in `afterEach`, since that is the end of the routing middleware chain.  If you remove the `next` from `afterEach`, it should work again:

```js
router.afterEach((routeTo, routeFrom) => {
  NProgress.done();
});
```

Here is [a link to the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks)

Comment: Perfect! Indeed, in the console was the error. Thank you so much! :D